# What does GetMemoryManagerState, ReservedAddressSpace do in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a code and It gives me some numbers. I don't know what do these numbers mean. I am curious, what these numbers mean. Thank you for your answer!

```
procedure usdmem(var stradd,stpadd:array of Integer);
var
st: TMemoryManagerState;
sb: TSmallBlockTypeState;
i:Integer;
begin
 GetMemoryManagerState(st);
 i:=0;
 for  sb in st.SmallBlockTypeStates do
 begin
   stradd[i]:=sb.ReservedAddressSpace;
   stpadd[i]:=stradd[i]+sb.UseableBlockSize*8;
   inc(i);
 end;
end;
//-----------------------------------
usdmem(stradd,stpadd);
for I := 0 to 10 do
begin
  Write(inttostr(stradd[I]));
  Write(' - ');
  WriteLn(inttostr(stpadd[I]));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The information can be found in the program documentation: [TMemoryManagerState](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMemoryManagerState). And there's more information available in a number of topics index from [Memory Management Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Managing_Memory_Index).

If you want to really understand how FastMM works, then you should [download and read the source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/). For example, that defines `TSmallBlockTypeState` like so:

```
TSmallBlockTypeState = record
  {The internal size of the block type}
  InternalBlockSize: Cardinal;
  {Useable block size: The number of non-reserved bytes inside the block.}
  UseableBlockSize: Cardinal;
  {The number of allocated blocks}
  AllocatedBlockCount: NativeUInt;
  {The total address space reserved for this block type (both allocated and
   free blocks)}
  ReservedAddressSpace: NativeUInt;
end;
```

As you can see, the comments document the record's fields.